# Auto-generated files (Silverlight *.g.i.cs files) dont' seem ignored when Treat warnings as errors is on

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, static-analysis

I'm trying to be a good dev and turn on treat warnings as errors (as I have always done in the past). The biggest difference is that this time, I'm using Silverlight 4 which generates a ton of code. All of the code starts something like this:

```
#pragma checksum <some stuff>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.1
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//---------
```

However, the treat warnings as errors is not ignoring it. I was under the impression that including such a header would cause the file to be ignored. Apparently, I'm wrong. Does anyone have a (clean) suggestion?

Comment: No, the compiler does *not* parse comments.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with the compiler. It has to do with the static code analysis tool. This tool typically runs in tandem with a compilation, but can do whatever it wants with comments... including tell you that they're missing for methods, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that, at least in my case, the only warnings coming from the generated files were resulting from my creation of a custom base Silverlight page that my pages inherited from. You can fix the issue of compiler warnings resulting from this type of scenario by removing the XAML file from the project and re-adding the xaml.cs code-behind file back to the project. This causes the LayoutRoot to not be defined, and the code generator to not generate the InitializeComponent method for this base class. Hopefully this will help someone else, too!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I deleted all the BIN and OBJ folders from solution directory (to make a smaller backup file of the source files).

I changed the **Target Silverlight Version** in **Project Properties** from SL4 to SL3 and then switched backed to SL4. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a long while to find out an acceptable workaround - but it's much better than changing the Target Silverlight version.

The workaround, as mentioned at [MSDN](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/559348/build-errors-due-to-incorrectly-generated-type-names-in-xxx-g-i-cs), is deleting all your *.g.i.cs files prior to the build.

Here is an F# script to do this (as found in the MSDN workarounds section):

```
open System
open System.IO

let deleteUserFile file =
    printfn "%s" file
    File.Delete(file)

Directory.GetFiles( @".", "*g.i.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories )
|> Array.iter deleteUserFile
```

This solved the error. Next time it shows up, all I have to is execute a file that'll clean all the g.i.cs files in my projects folder.

**Edit:** I upgraded to Silverlight 5 and have this issue happen again. None of the suggestions listed here worked (switching to SL4 then back to SL5 or only deleting the g.i.cs files)- however deleting the BIN and OBJ folders of the Silverlight project did the trick.

Comment: Hi thanks for this it really helped. With Silverlight 5, you can still use the script but what else you need is also delete the generated file with the suffix .g.cs. :)